# Word Mail Merge from ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, mailmerge

What is the best way to do this. I dont have access to the database since it is firewalled. It needs to be done throught the web interface.

I can generate a csv file and plug it into the word document, but it seems cumbersome to me. Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Edit:For future reference i ended up using a library called Syncfusion DocIO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Automating Word Mail merge from ASP.NET application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/8057f960-8f61-4554-bad2-5cb34553b316)

Comment: Thanks I end up using a library called Syncfusion DocIO

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a link. Please post the relevant information from that link to here.

Answer (score 1):

OfficeWriter is a third-party library that lets you do mail merges in ASP.NET with DOC or DOCX.  You didn't specify which file format you needed - Leniel's suggestion will work for DOCX, but if you need DOC (binary) support your best bet is with a third-party.

Automating Office on the server is never a good idea (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

http://www.officewriter.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed NTemplates? Not exactly for Word documents but if you don't mind using RTF, it might be the solution. Download full source code and examples for free from ntemplates.codeplex.com